# HashMap & HashSet size() in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I tried to find information about it but failed.

How is `size()` in `HashMap` or `HashSet` implemented? How does it work? Is it an `O(1)` or `O(n)` operation?

Comment: The source code is open, you can have a look: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.size%28%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes `O(1)` time. `HashMap` has a `size` instance variable that gets modified when entries are added or removed:

This is the `HashMap` implementation:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.
 *
 * @return the number of key-value mappings in this map
 */
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

`HashSet` calls `size()` of the backing `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and sharing the resource.